# C# File is in Use By Another Program

Tags: c#, file-io

```
System.IO.File.CreateText(@"C:\\ProgramData\\Password Manager\\pwd.dat");
```

This makes the file perfectly.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\\ProgramData\\Password Manager\\pwd.dat", pwd);
```

But this line gets an error

> "The process cannot access the file 'C:\ProgramData\Password Manager\pwd.dat' because it is being used by another process."

Is there a way to close the file before writing to it?

Comment: Did you `Close` and/or `Dispose` the result of [`CreateText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext.aspx)? Why do you call `CreateText` first? [`WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines.aspx) is documented as *Creates a new file...*

Comment: Just fixed it. Since I didn't set the file up as a variable. I didn't have the option to close it. Just made it a variable, closed it, than it worked.!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `CreateText`. Simply call `WriteAllLines` and that will create the file for you. At the moment the stream returned by `CreateText` is holding onto the file it created which is the reason why the error is thrown.

Answer (score 4):

File.CreateText not only create the file, but open it and returns a stream to write the file.
Your subsequent call finds the file blocked by yourself

Try

```
StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(@"C:\\ProgramData\\Password Manager\\pwd.dat");
sw.Close();
sw.Dispose();
```

or simply

```
using(File.CreateText(@"C:\\ProgramData\\Password Manager\\pwd.dat"))  {}
```

(The [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) takes care to close and dispose the file)

however, this is completely unnecessary seeing your code because [File.WriteAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines.aspx) creates the file if it doesn't exist.